# magereport can not recognize security patch 6788 on my site although I've already applied it

Tags: magento, patch

My site have patch 6788 applied but magereport.com still deagree with it.

I looked though this patch technical page: https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details
to see what changed they added, it's all there on my site code base.

I've updated .htaccess  and .htaccess.sample

Did anyone get same issue before and have some solution to sort it ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2):

**If you get an unexpected result**

> Are you running multiple Magento installations on the same domain? Due to the way Magento routing works, MageReport cannot distinguish between multiple installations on the same domain. So if you want to test an upgrade, you could put it on its own domain (eg. test.yourdomain.com).
>   Log on to SSH (shell)
>
> Every check that’s been installed can easily be found in the content of your shop. More specifically it’s logged in **app/etc/applied.patches.list**.
>
> So you run this command 'grep' via SSH to access the list of applied security patches:

```
grep '|' app/etc/applied.patches.list
```

> For More Information,Kindly visit below URL:- https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-magento-patch-supee-6788/
>
> Hope It's helpful for you.